# Comments on wordpress author profile page

Tags: wordpress, comments

I'm trying to figure out how to allow users to comments on an authors profile page (where it displays recent posts by xxx). Anyone have any idea where I would even start?

I don't think I'll be able even inserts comments into the comments table in mysql because of the comment_post_ID conflict. Unless I inserted authors comments as a{AUTH-ID} so there would be no number conflicts (with the post id).

But how would I do this? Bad coding practice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

See the top answer on this page, it's the best method of getting comments working on author pages :

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8996/author-page-comments-and-ratings

Be sure to avoid use the Wordpress plugin 'Author Page Comments' which claims to to what you want, but is reported as unworking and potentially vulnerable to security problems.